# Is there a way to work free for experience?

Tags: freelance-websites, difficult-client, working-from-home, project, contract-to-hire

I had never been hired at upwork, I don't know why.
I am willing to work for experience!
Just simple data entry jobs, just for my experience.
Because I think I need experience to be hired by an actual job.

Is there a way to do that?

Comments and advice please! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to a website like www.freelancer.com and offer your service for free or a very small price.

Freelancer.com allows you to interact with people who need projects to be done and some of the projects are simple and some are very complex.  There is a way to only see projects with the skills that you possess.

If you want to do it for free, what you would do is find a project that you feel that you can do.  From there you could bid on that project and set the amount to $0 or if it doesn't allow you to do it for $0 then you could put it as low as it will allow you to.

If you want to really get something quickly then I would look for the ones that are listed as urgent.  I've done a couple of those and was surprised to see that a few of them responded to my bid almost immediately.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't work for free, but for a very low fare, **clearly stating why**.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the client to give you a test task for **1-2 hours** which you will do free of charge or at a very basic rate.

Working for free will never guarantee receiving strong feedback from clients. Also, As far as I know according to the rule of upwork, If you do a project of less than **$5** then it will not show client feedback on your public profile. So no! There's no point in working for free.

Everything is your public profile on upwork. That is one way to attract and impress clients.